# Work with somebody else on the same project and the same bundle ID

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

So my client has invited me under their Apple ID as a developer team member. How do we work on the same project together?

The reason I ask this is because whenever I try to run the app on my device Xcode complains with

> The app ID "com.bundle-id-that-client-registered-under-their-account" **cannot be registered** to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.

The bundle ID the Xcode project is using is registered under my client account. This means that I should either find a way to work with it or change it (this would mean that I would have to interchange bundle ID every time we work together with git). Any hints on how to fix this?

Comment: I would just change the bundle ID to one I can build and then write a git pre-commit hook to stop myself from accidentally committing the bundle ID change https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks Or even better have it ignore that change automatically.

Comment: @AllenR Great idea, feel free to answer

Comment: If you are a member of the client's team then you will need to get the appropriate certificate from them and install it in your machine. You can then select that team for the code signing in your Xcode project and you should be good

Comment: @Paulw11 which certificates would I have to ask for exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just change the bundle ID to one I can build and then write a git pre-commit hook to stop myself from accidentally committing the bundle ID change, [Git Docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). Or even better have it ignore that change automatically.

The Bundle ID is stored in the .pbxproj file for your project. I think a simple way of checking would be doing a grep (text search) in the file for your exact bundle ID you are using and stopping the commit if you find it.

Another way is by checking out this gem created by the CocoaPods community which helps when working with Xcode project files.

https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj

Comment: Hopefully finding the file I want to ignore won't be too challenging.

Comment: I added a little more info you might want to view. It shouldn't be very hard to find your bundle ID in the file.